# Is that possible Github to do automatic merge?

Tags: github

I sent out a pull request in Github, after some time, I saw the branch to be automatically merged commit to master from my branch. I did not make this. Is that possible Github to do that with some automatic configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you "send out" a PR (as in "[Creating the PR](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)" and "[Sending the PR](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/#sending-the-pull-request)"), it means you are not the owner of the destination repo (the one which receives the PR)

That owner would have done the merge (See "[Merging the PR](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/)"). Not GitHub.